# I want to add diagonal text in a transparent image as a watermark. But that text should be dynamic

Tags: python, automation

I want to add diagonal text in a transparent image as a watermark. But that text should be dynamic. I have attached the image. I want to do something like that.

I used the code but its noting showing in the text.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


img = Image.new("RGB", (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))


width, height = img.size

watermark = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(watermark)

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 24)
text = "Your Text"

diagonal_len = int((width ** 2 + height ** 2) ** 0.5)

text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(text, font=font)

num_repetitions = int(diagonal_len / text_width) + 1
long_text = text * num_repetitions

for i in range(num_repetitions):
    draw.text((i * text_width, -i * text_width), long_text, font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128))

watermark = watermark.rotate(45, expand=1)

overlay = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)
draw.text((50, 50), "Your Transparent Text", font=font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 128))

watermark.alpha_composite(overlay)

img.paste(watermark, (0, 0), watermark)

img.save("watermarked_image.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparent white text `(255, 255, 255, 128)` on a white background won't show up. Try using transparent grey: `(128, 128, 128, 128)`.